# Eslint gives error: Configuration for rule "strict" is invalid: Value "error" is the wrong type

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, eslint

I tried to use Eslint with the following option:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "indent": [
      2,
      2,
      {
        "SwitchCase": 1
      }
    ],
    "space-before-function-paren": [
      2,
      {
        "anonymous": "always",
        "named": "never"
      }
    ],
    "no-use-before-define": [
      2,
      "nofunc"
    ],
    // TODO: turn on later
    "comma-dangle": [
      0
    ],
    "prefer-template": 0
  },
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "airbnb/base"
  ]
}
```

And I am getting the error:

Error: ... ... /node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/index.js:
    Configuration for rule "strict" is invalid:
    Value "error" is the wrong type.

Referenced from: airbnb/base

I think that this value: 'error' is causing the error.

**eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/strict.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    // babel inserts `'use strict';` for us
    strict: ['error', 'never']
  }
};
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

[Severity configuration strings](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/70e3a0297537eb1d84a0bf5cf764c01a792191fc) (`"off"`, `"warn"` and `"error"`) were introduced in version 2.3.0 of ESLint. Upgrading to that - or a later - version should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the eslint resource file `.eslintrc.json` in your project root with the "rules.semi" set, you can also have this problem.

This sample resource file can fix the error

```
$ cat .eslintrc.json 
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": "error"
    }
}
```